# Breeze.js is not returning related table even with "expand" specified in query

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I have checked in my asp.net code and at the point I have the "game" entity loaded, it also has the related "gamesets" entity loaded too.

Using chrome's network resources panel I can see that the query is running from breeze and it's picking up the base "game" entity but it's got "null" for the related gamesets.

partial result of the metadata lookup:

```
,\"navigationProperty\":[{\"name\":\"Sets\",\"relationship\":\"Self.GameSet_Game\"
```

So you can see that "Sets" exists.

This is the query it's running:

```
    var query = new entityModel.EntityQuery()
            .from("Games")
            .expand("Sets")
            .orderBy("GameDateTime");
```

Here's a partial bit of the network resources result from the breeze query:

```
ID: 1
LeagueGame: true
MVP: null
MVP_PersonID: 3
Opponent: "Test Opponent"
Sets: null
```

You can also see that the 1:1 relationship for MVP isn't being picked up from the breeze query, but it is when I do a test call using asp.net standard code... anyone got any idea why this would be?  Breeze can see the relationship in the metadata and yet it won't load the related entity.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.  I had used the "BreezyDevices" Julie Lerman example and for some reason that doesn't have the "[BreezeController]" attribute.  I added this to my controller class and bingo, it all works. :-)